Edit crontab without use of exec(), shell_exec(), etc
I'm trying to see if there is a method to editing cron jobs without the of use of the exec() or shell_exec() functions. My host has disabled those functions for security reasons. I've read methods on updating crontab items in and out of Stack Overflow (for instance at how to edit crontab with PHP shell_exec and how to edit crontab with PHP shell_exec), but all the solutions I've found require me to use the shell_exec() or exec() function, which I can't do. Is there a method to update cron jobs without the use of these functions?
Note: I don't necessarily need to add or delete items, just update their frequency. (But I imagine if I can update, I'd be able to add and delete.)

Instead of changing the crontab file, schedule the job to run as often as needed and implement the tracking of actual executions inside the job itself (I suppose the job is a PHP script). You can keep the schedule and the tracking in two JSON files (that you can write using file_put_contents()). The job can read them and decide if it has to do something or it will just exit. This way you can manage the schedule without needing to change the crontab file. Bonus, you don't need to take care to not change the lines of the crontab that are not related to your job.

The basic answer to your question is no.  The crontab command is set-gid, because the crontab files are not accessible by unprivileged processes. You can't emulate what it does without this special privilege.

Something similar to what axiac suggests. You could write a cron job that periodically runs the crontab command to copy a file in your home directory to your crontab, e.g. * * * * * crontab ~/crontab.txt. The PHP script can update crontab.txt. If you want to get fancy, you could use a timestamp file to record the last time you updated crontab, and only update if the txt file is newer.

Similar to what @Barmar / @axiac suggested, always put a path to a script or that generic crontab [ -u user ] file entry, then control that file. That could be basically file() and file_put_conents(). You get an array with one line per file you can relatively easily edit, then store it back w/ the second function. https://php.net/file https://php.net/file_put_contents

I recommend using a single file to manage all your cron needs. You will call this file every minute * * * * * but the main thing this file will do is take advantage of package dragonmantank/cron-expression to decide if and when to execute scripts, in code. Very flexible and easy to manage.

Install with composer https://packagist.org/packages/dragonmantank/cron-expression

Make a single cron job - the last one you will ever need - * * * * * /use/bin/php /path/to/your/tick.php

Prepare a tick file


tick.php:

// every hour
$schedule = "20 * * * *";
$script = '/path/to/job.php';

// main logic, decide if to run job
$cron = Cron\CronExpression::factory($schedule);
if ($cron->isDue()) {
    require ($script);
}

Of course now you can prepare an array with as many jobs as you want:
$arr_jobs = [
    [
        'schedule' => '0 0 * * *',
        'script' => 'job1.php',
    ],
    [
        'schedule' => '0 12 * * 5',
        'script' => 'job2.php',
    ],
];

Updated tick.php:
foreach ($arr_jobs as $job) {
    $schedule = $job['schedule'];
    $script = $job['script'];

    // main logic, decide if to run job
    $cron = Cron\CronExpression::factory($schedule);
    if ($cron->isDue()) {
        require ($script);
    }
}


So you're basically suggesting that they implement their own cron using this library.

Yes. I use this tick.php file on most projects I make
